# Strange git diff behavior

Tags: git, branch, diff, git-diff

I'm on branch `A` and branch `B` is ahead of it. I want to see the changes in `B` from `A`, but when I run `git diff B` it shows its additions as deletions and vice-versa, and if I want to put `B`'s changes into the working copy of `A` (desirable if I have a test offshoot branch), trying to run `git diff B > Bfile` then `git apply Bfile` just throws a bunch of errors.

If I instead type `git diff A..B` (I'm already on `A`) it shows the correct changes.

So why does the first command show the changes as deletions when they're additions? It seems redundant and counter-intuitive to have to type out the branch I'm already on when I just want the accurate changes with another branch.

Answer (score 1):

(Note that `git diff A B` is synonymous with `git diff A..B`,so I'll use both interchangeably in this answer.)

The behavior you described is because `git diff B` is equivalent to `git diff B HEAD`, which shows the changes *from* `B` *to* `HEAD`. Your workaround, `git diff A..B` is valid (as would be `git diff HEAD..B`). To skip the requirement to specify the `A` branch, (or `HEAD`), do:

```
git diff ..B
```

This will tell Git to fill in `HEAD` on the left instead, so it's equivalent to `git diff HEAD..B`.

Comment: You can also abbreviate `HEAD` as `@`, e.g., `git diff @ B`.  And, you can use `-R` to reverse the direction of a diff, so you can write this as `git diff -R B`.  (I would just write out HEAD, it's not that hard to type and it seems clearest :-) )